# как подключиться с одного компа к 10 вайфай сетям?

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, администрирование

Как подключиться с одного хоста одновременно к 10 вайфай сетям?

Comment: Зачем вам это? Какие вы преследуете цели? Какие контроллеры у ваших wifi-карт?

Comment: Цели исследовательские. Карты не принципиальны с точки зрения эксперимента, если только с точки зрения экономии

Answer (score 0):

> хоста одновременно к 10 вайфай сетям?

- с одного адаптера - никак.

Почти все WiFi адеплеры поддерживают максимум 4 интерфейса.

Большинство их них может запустить в режиме STA (станция, подключаемая к точке доступа) только один мастер интерфейс.

Адаптер может работать только в одном канале.

Нужно подключить 10 адаптеров и через обычные настройки операционной системы подключить каждый к своей сети.

Чтоб работала маршрутизация каждая вайфай сеть должна быть в отдельной ip подсети или в отдельном неймспейсе.